# Facebook api: cant access albums with privacy option set to friends

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making an app where a user can select a photo from one of their facebook albums. When they select a album I call: 'albumId + "/picture"' to get a list of the photos in that album. I have had to add a check response.data[a].privacy == "everyone" otherwise no photos are returned by that album if its privacy setting is "friends". Even though its an album that belongs to the user and the user created it they cant select photos from it. Is there something I am missing or is this a rule facebook has?

```
$('.btn-facebook').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var index = $(this).data('index');

            $("#albums").html("");
            albumsString = "<img src='/Content/images/albums.png' />";
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;

                    $.colorbox({
                        href: '/Game/Albums',
                        innerWidth: 488,
                        innerHeight: 588,
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0,
                        onComplete: function () {
                        }
                    });

                    FB.api('/me/albums', function (response) {
                        for (var a = 0; a < response.data.length; a++) {
                            if (response.data[a].count != null) {
                                if (response.data[a].count > 0) {
                                    if (response.data[a].privacy != null) {
                                        if (response.data[a].privacy == "everyone") {
                                            GetImg(response.data[a].id, index);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
            }, { scope: 'email, user_likes, publish_actions, user_photos, friends_photos' });
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the user_photos permission from the user whose albums you're trying to access? You should be able to get all the photos of your app's current user using their access token

Comment: Yes, you can see it above. tried friends_photos as well.

Comment: I really cant understand what are you trying to do with the `privacy`. Of-course you'll get no photos with "everyone" privacy if there is none. If you simply wish to extract all the photos, just remove this privacy check and that's it!

Comment: Turned out to be a red herring. the id (think its a long) that was returned by facebook needed to be forced to a string, the id was being changed to a different number by the js when i passed it to another function. GOD KNOWS WHY